# glGetBufferSubData and glMapBufferRange for GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER very slow on NVIDIA GTX960M

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader-storage-buffer

I've been having some issues with transfering a GPU buffer into CPU for performing sorting operations. The buffer is a `GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER` composed of 300.000 float values. The transfer operation with `glGetBufferSubData` is taking around 10ms, and with `glMapBufferRange`, it takes more than 100 ms.

The code Im using is the following:

```
std::vector<GLfloat> viewRow;
unsigned int viewRowBuffer = -1;
int length = -1;

void bindRowBuffer(unsigned int buffer){
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 3, buffer);
}

void initRowBuffer(unsigned int &buffer, std::vector<GLfloat> &row, int lengthIn){
    // Generate and initialize buffer
    length = lengthIn;
    row.resize(length);
    memset(&row[0], 0, length*sizeof(float));
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    bindRowBuffer(buffer);
    glBufferStorage(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, row.size() * sizeof(float), &row[0], GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT | GL_MAP_READ_BIT | GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT);

    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0);
}

void cleanRowBuffer(unsigned int buffer) {
    float zero = 0.0;
    glClearNamedBufferData(buffer, GL_R32F, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, &zero);
}

void readGPUbuffer(unsigned int buffer, std::vector<GLfloat> &row) {
    glGetBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,0,length *sizeof(float),&row[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0);
}

void readGPUMapBuffer(unsigned int buffer, std::vector<GLfloat> &row) {
    float* data = (float*)glMapBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, length*sizeof(float), GL_MAP_READ_BIT); glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0);
     memcpy(&row[0], data, length *sizeof(float));
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER);
}
```

The main is doing:

```
    bindRowBuffer(viewRowBuffer);
    cleanRowBuffer(viewRowBuffer);
    countPixs.bind();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gPatch);
    countPixs.setInt("gPatch", 0);
    countPixs.run(SCR_WIDTH/8, SCR_HEIGHT/8, 1);
    countPixs.unbind();
    readGPUbuffer(viewRowBuffer, viewRow);
```

Where countPixs is a compute shader, but I'm possitive the problem is not there because if I comment the run command, the read takes exactly the same amount of time.

The weird thing is that if I execute a getbuffer of only 1 float:

```
glGetBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,0, 1 *sizeof(float),&row[0]);
```

It takes exactly the same time... so I'm guessing there is something wrong all-the-way... maybe related to the `GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER`?

Comment: Do you need write access to teh data or just read only?

Comment: read only is ok

Comment: A simpler way to achieve what you want at faster speeds might be to use a 1D texture array instead of an SSBO

Answer (score 3):

This is likely to be an GPU-CPU synchronization/round trip caused delay.
I.e., once you map your buffer, the previous GL command(s) that touched the buffer have to be completed immediately, causing a pipeline stall.
Note that drivers are lazy: it is very probable GL commands have *not even started executing* yet.

If you can: `glBufferStorage(..., GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT)` and map the buffer persistently. This avoids completely re-mapping and allocating any GPU memory, and you can keep the mapped pointer over draw calls with some caveats:

- You likely also need GPU fences to detect/wait when the data is actually available from GPU. (Unless you like reading garbage.)
- The mapped buffer can't be resized. (since you already use glBufferStorage() you are ok)
- It is probably good idea to combine GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT with GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT

After reading GL 4.5 [docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferStorage.xhtml) bit more I found out that `glFenceSync` is mandatory in order to guarantee the data has arrived from the GPU, even with GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT:

> If GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT is set and the server does a write, the app must call glFenceSync with GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE (or
> glFinish). Then the CPU will see the writes after the sync is
> complete.